# Cardinality restriction in OWL

Tags: owl

Saying `R exactly 18 C` means that there are exactly 18 individuals x_i as well as individuals y_i such that we have R(x_i,y_i) and all y_i are in C.

My question is: are the x_i individuals different? In other words will they necessarily be assigned to different domain elements in every interpretation?

I know that there is a `owl:Different` construct, but *is it assumed when we say `R exactly 18 C` or do I have to declare it every time I want 18 different individuals*?

Comment: "means that there are exactly 18 individuals x_i" -> that's wrong. `R exactly 18 C` is a class expression that describes a set of individuals `x_i` where each of those is known to have 18 relations via property `R` to some individual `y_j` with `j = 1, ..., 18` and each `y_i` belongs to `C`

Comment: in OWL there is no unique names assumption, so you have to explicitly declare individuals being semantically different - I mean yes, the class expressions `R exactly 18 C` requires/assumes 18 different individuals, so have to make those explicit to being considered in inference, e.g. when having axiom like `(R exactly 18 C) SubClassOf A`

Comment: `owl:Different` -> `owl:AllDifferent` you mean

Comment: Yes I misspelled it, I meant that for each x in ``R exactly 18 C`` there are 18 y_i such that we have R(x,y_i), and the question was whether the y_i are different. You say no, and that'w what I suspected, but how can I express that the y_i of every x in ``R exactly 18 C`` are different without explicitly naming them?

Comment: they are different, that's why it only works if you have this defined explicitly in your OWL ontology